# How to add custom filter to HttpSecurity and retrieve the user? (Spring Security)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

In `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class we have `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)` method where we add restrictions to request. What i want is:

1.Retrieve a user who wants to enter
2.Check if that user is present in db
3.Check if that user has a special propery, for example.: `login.endsWith('_login')`

Comment: you should do validation in controller where you enter the form with login and password and just invoke database method which check if user exists

Comment: @RafałSokalski Yes i can get the user in controller but it seems weird. So for example if i have 20 controller methods, i must check the user in each of them?

Comment: You make only one controller where you enter user to application

Comment: Why are you supposed to check user in each controller ?

Comment: @RafałSokalski aaa i get it. But i can't do that in my case, because i'm using Keycloak (Authorization Server). It provides its own login page.

Comment: I have never worked before with Keycloak but I founded some tutorial how to connect it with Spring Security [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak)

Comment: @RafałSokalski i implemented example in this tutorial. Everything works fine. The problem is: in `configure(HttpSecurity http)` i added  `antMatcher("/protected").hasRole("user")`. And my app give a permission to user if he has the role above. Good! But what i want is something like this:  `antMatcher("/protected").getUserLogin().endsWith("_login") `.Like "give a permission to see the /protected page only for those whose login ends with "_login"".... I need to do custom validation.And for that i need to somehow get the user who tries to login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to implement Custom AuthenticationProvider. Do the authentication code by other server as you need.

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider
  implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
      throws AuthenticationException {

        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        if (shouldAuthenticateAgainstThirdPartySystem()) {

            // use the credentials
            // and authenticate against the third-party system
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
              name, password, new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(
          UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

And register your Authentication provider.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(
      AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

> Note : I am assuming you're using HTTP Basic Authentication, you can to
>   change it to FormLogin or as per your need.

Comment: Man, you are the best!

Comment: Thanks! Happy to help

Comment: Btw. I'm trying to autowire JdbcTemplate to this CustomAuthProvider, but it's null. Don't you know why? (p.s. I can autowire JdbcTemplate in my controllers by the way)

Comment: No it is not recommended that way, what you do implement UserDetailsService. You can refer from https://github.com/gaurav072/spring-boot-blog/blob/master/src/main/java/com/startwithjava/simpleblog/security/config/AppSecurityConfig.java

Comment: should I set UserDetailsService  in this method?   `@Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }`

Comment: Have you implemented authentication there? Why you need JdbcTemplate? For UserDetailsService implementation you can take a look http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database

Comment: I'm using Keycloak (runnable server which handles authentication). Users are stored in Keycloak's internal db as well as in my own db. But in my db they also have roles. I want something like:  `.antMatcher("/securedPage").hasRole("secure");` .For that i need to catch the user who tries to login, check if this user is present in my db and set roles to that user (in token). So for example i set "secure" role to userA and he can pass.

Comment: in that case you should autowired the DAO/spring repository in KeycloakAuthenticationProvider to get the user roles. As you have already have authentication mechanism over KeyCloak only you need to do authorization part.

Comment: "you should autowired the DAO/spring repository to the user roles". Where should i autowire what? I just need to extract string array of that user's roles and add them to token. So when `.antMatchers("/securedPage").hasRole("secure"); `  part came. It will look to token's roles.

Comment: You mean i should autowire "rolesRepository" to my authentication provider?

Comment: That's the problem :) My autowired repository is null :(((

Comment: @Gourav Srivastav Maaan, it's working now :))) The problem was that the method `keycloakAuthenticationProvider()` was returning  `new KeycloakAuthProvider()` . I did `@Autowire  KeycloakAuthProvider provider`  and returned it. Now everything works :) Thank you again, dude you saved my day!